# all functions being skipped and code is running without them

Tags: c

I have fixed my code style and have updated what it looks like, but it's skipping all the rounds and inputs I want to make
If I formatted the returns wrong(Which is what I'm thinking), or I didn't nest my functions properly, those are the only issues I can imagine would be wrong

```
#define ROUNDS 3
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int main()
{
    //Greets the user at the start of the round
    void greeting();{
        printf("Welcome to the Toothpick Game!\n");
        printf("Here are the rules.\n");
        printf("There are currently 31 toothpicks on the table.\n");
        printf("You and I will each get a turn to pick either 1, 2, or 3 toothpick off the table.\n");
        printf("The player that gets to puck the last toothpicks looses the game!\n");
        printf("Sounds easy right? Well lets see if you can beat me!\n");
        printf("Ready to play?... Here we go!\n");
    } //display welcome message to user
    
    for(int x = 0; x < ROUNDS; ++x)
    {
        int result = playRound(x + 1); //call playRound and assign result the value function returns
        
        void winnerAnnouncment(int user);{//overall winner of round announcement

        } 
    }
    printf("********************************************************\n");
    printf("Thank you for playing!\n");
    return 0;
}

int playRound(int round)
{

    int toothpicks = 31; //number of toothpicks to start with
    int winner, taken, choice, leftover;

    printf("Welcome to a new round %d!\n", round);
    printf("You may go first!\n");
    
        int leftOnTable(int toothpicks, int taken);{ //calculate number of toothpicks left
            toothpicks = toothpicks - taken;        

            while(toothpicks != 0)//loop to control playing of the game
            {
                int humanPick();{ //retrieve the user's guess
                    int userchoice;
                    printf("How many toothpicks do you want to take? ");
                    scanf("%d", &taken);
                    printf("Okay... You took %d off the table", taken);
                    if (toothpicks = 1)
                        winner = 0;


                    int computerPick(int choice, int leftover);{ //computer makes its pick
                
                        if (toothpicks > 4){//Caculates what the computer will take based off of the users choice
                            choice = 4 - userchoice;
                            toothpicks = toothpicks - choice;
                            leftover = choice;
                            printf("I am taking %d toothpicks off the table.", choice);
                        }
                

                        if(toothpicks = 2 || 3 || 4)//calculates how many toothpicks the computer will take to leave one left on the table
                            if (toothpicks == 2){
                                choice = toothpicks - 1;
                                leftover = 1;
                                printf("I am taking %d toothpicks off the table.", choice);
                            }
                            if (toothpicks == 3){
                                choice = toothpicks - 1;
                                printf("I am taking %d toothpicks off the table.", choice);
                            }
                            if (toothpicks == 4){
                                choice = toothpicks - 1;
                                leftover = 1;
                                printf("I am taking %d toothpicks off the table.", choice);
                            }
                            if (toothpicks = 1){
                                choice = 1;
                                leftover = 0;
                                toothpicks = leftover;
                                winner = 1;
                                printf("I will take the last toothpick.");
                            }
                
                    } 
                } 

        

                return toothpicks; 
            }               
            
            
            
        }
    
    return round; 
}
```

[image: Text]

Comment: Well, the first thing I spotted was `if(toothpicks = 1)`, in two places.

Comment: Easy mistake to make.  Good compilers warn about it.  If your compiler isn't giving you helpful warnings about easy mistakes (of which C has plenty!), learning C is going to be even more frustrating.

Comment: This test:  `if(toothpicks = 2 || 3 || 4)` needs to be `if (toothpicks == 2 || toothpicks == 3 || toothpicks == 4)`

Comment: Also, learn to use `else if` where appropriate.

Comment: I'm guessing no one ever taught you to write a conditional like `if(toothpicks = 2 || 3 || 4)`.  I'm guessing you just guessed/hoped that might work.  But guessing is no way to learn C!  A good C book will teach you what the operators are, and how to combine them into larger, valid expressions.  But there's no way (in C) to directly say "if X is equal to Y or Z".

Comment: my compiler (gnu,gcc) allows me to nest functions and will compile correctly

Comment: Yeah, well its in a tiny minority, and that isn't a good thing. And fyi, that isn't a nested implementation anyway. Remove that semi-colon in `void greeting();{` and see if it still compiles. All that code does right now is declare (not define; just declare) a function `greetings` taking no arguments and returning `void`, that doesn't even exists, then opens a local scope containing seven printf calls. that isn't a nested function whatsoever. And if you [turn up you warnings and treated them as errors](https://godbolt.org/z/rjhxrhPac) it might be educational

Comment: The indentation below `if(toothpicks = 2 || 3 || 4)` (or its replacement, see other comment) is misleading. If you want to have more than one `if` nested in the outer `if` you need braces around the block. C is not Python where indentation is part of the syntax. GCC should print many warnings, maybe you have to enable more warnings. See e.g. https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/

Comment: If the question here is about nested functions, my advice to you is, "Do *not* use nested functions."  It's confusing, it's not necessary here, it's not portable, and it's clouding anyone's ability to get to the bottom of your program's real problems.

Comment: Even if you want to use nested functions, do it correctly. What are all those semicolons doing there? (`int computerPick(int choice, int leftover);{`)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple times throughout the code used is an assignment operator `=` instead of the `==` likely intended.
In addition, the following:

- `userchoice` is never initialized to a value.
- Nested functions aren't supported by the C standard.
- Numerous semicolons are found before the function definitions (e.g. `void greeting();{...}`).

  - This declares, but doesn't define the function. The following is code that executes in a new code block (new scope).
- Incorrect `||` operator usage in conditionals (Broken:`toothpicks == 2 || 3 || 4` Fixed: `toothpicks == 2 || toothpicks == 3 || toothpicks == 4`).

  - This condition would always be true. The conditional `toothpicks == 2` is tested, if this proves untrue the conditional `3` is tested. `3` is true, and so this condition is always true.
- The functions `leftOnTable` and `greeting` are never called.
- Additional unused variables include: `result` and `winner`

Other logical errors may exist.
This should answer, if only partially, why the program isn't working as expected. Perhaps with more information about why nested functions are being used and the intended functionality of the program, I could provide a working code fix to every present issue.